# Restore files from git

Tags: git, file, atom-editor, restore

I worked on a new Projekt. I added all the Files to my local git-repository

```
git add .
```

but i didn't commit it. Then i accidently resetet the git

```
git reset --hard
```

How is it possible to restore my Files? I hoped, that atom kept the files, but also there, the files where not open anymore. Nevermind, that atom would close all my files.

Comment: `Then i accidently resetet the git` ... typing `git reset --hard` by accident seems a bit unlikely.  In any case, your changes are gone from both the working directory and the index, so if there is no backup in your IDE then you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

When you `git add` a file, `git` stores it as an object in your repository (in the `.git` directory).  Your files are probably still hanging around.  On the other hand, by running the `git reset --hard` command you have lost any information about the file *names*.

You can see the objects themselves by running:

```
find .git/objects -type f
```

Which will produce something like:

```
.git/objects/67/6e8ff99e42b61f96bb0107fa1dff59594eba07
.git/objects/7c/45d8f7d987c584a8d61a8d75431ddd4f1ba52f
```

You can see the contents of those objects with the `git cat-file` command, as in:

```
git cat-file -p 7c45d8f7d987c584a8d61a8d75431ddd4f1ba52f
```

Note that the object id is the concatenation of the two characters in the first level directory followed by all the characters of the filename.

So it would be fairly trivial to write a script that would restore the *contents* of all your files, but you would have to manually rename them after the fact.

Comment: What if they are many of different file types? How can I restore them?